# C# application with simple database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I want to build an application that indexes files in a database. This database will be accessed by another app to read the files data.

Both will be run as a service.

What is the best database? SQL Express, Compact, Access file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the databases you mentioned I would pick SQL Express.

I wouldn't share the database across programs using SQL Compact and Access lacks locking capabilities to allow many concurrent users.

Comment: With read-only access, you'd likely be able to support large numbers of users with a Jet/ACE data file. I'm not necessarily recommending it, but just pointing out that for the outlined application, you'd be able to have more users than you would with a read/write app.

Answer (score 3):

You might want take a look at SQLite. There is a [.NET Wrapper](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) for easy use.

Comment: I did not find it easy to deal with!

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I used [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/). A pure .NET solution that also works rather well in a multi-user scenario, with simply XCOPY deployment (just ship a DLL within your application folder; maybe even ILMerge would work).

Since it now has its third owner (if I counted correctly), I am really unsure whether to base future projects on this tool.

From a performance perspective, MDB is faster than VistaDB.